# What is #pragma used for in OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to understand the meaning and usage of `#pragma` in `OpenMP`, I have this small sample code:

```
int main()
{
omp_set_num_threads(16);
#pragma omp parallel
{
printf( "Hello, World!\n" );
}
return 0;
}
```

I can't understand what is pragma for, that is the first time I see it being used in `C`. I know that the entire line is to indicate the start of the parallel part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-directives?view=msvc-160 and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pragma directive is used to access compiler-specific preprocessor extensions. Using the following format:

`#pragma compiler specific extension`

Which means that you're telling your compiler to expand the directive and turn it into a runnable code that uses the desired extension functionality.

It depends entirely on the compiler being used, so if you use a really old GCC/Clang you might not have all the functionalities of OpenMP or perhaps none at all.

If you want to go deeper into the `#pragma` subject you can follow these links:

1. [GNU GCC C++ Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html)
2. [CProgramming](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/pragma.html)
3. [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-160)
4. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Compiler-specific_preprocessor_features)

Comment: Although this is approximately correct, I have to quibble with some of the details.  (1) `#pragma`s are indeed preprocessor directives, but the compiler-specific extensions they engage are not necessarily scoped specifically to the preprocessor. (2) `#pragma` directives do not necessarily themselves expand to runnable code.  In fact, I daresay that most do not -- where such a thing is wanted, a system-defined macro serves better.  `#pragma`s do, typically, affect what code the compiler generates, but that's not the same thing.